# How to fix " No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'" error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create a df and connect it a calendar in dash. I believe everything in the code is working, however, when I ran it, I'm getting an error that said:  `No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'`

Here's my code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

raw = [['tom', 10, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')], ['nick', 15, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')], ['juli', 14, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')],['tom', 8, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')],
        ['nick', 4, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')], ['juli', 12, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')]]
df = pd.DataFrame(raw, columns=['Name', 'Apples Gathered', 'date'])

#App layout
app = dash.Dash(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='datepicker',
        display_format='DD-MM-YYYY',
        first_day_of_week=1,
        max_date_allowed=dt.today(),
    ),
])
dash_table.DataTable(
       id='datatable',
       columns=[
            {'id': 'Name', 'name': 'Name'},
            {'id': 'Apples Gathered', 'name': 'Apples Gathered'},
            {'id': 'date', 'name': 'Date'}],

        data = df.to_dict('records'),
)

@app.callback(
       Output('datatable', 'data'),
       [Input('datepicker', 'start_date'),
       Input('date-picker', 'end_date')]
)
def update_table(start_date, end_date):
   dff = (df.groupby(['Name', 'Apples Gathered']).sum())
   return dff.to_dict('records')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Here's the version of the packages installed in the environment:

```
Package                   Version
------------------------- -------
Brotli                    1.0.9
click                     7.1.2
dash                      1.19.0
dash-bootstrap-components 0.11.3
dash-core-components      1.15.0
dash-html-components      1.1.2
dash-renderer             1.9.0
dash-table                4.11.2
Flask                     1.1.2
Flask-Compress            1.9.0
future                    0.18.2
itsdangerous              1.1.0
Jinja2                    2.11.3
MarkupSafe                1.1.1
numpy                     1.20.1
pandas                    1.2.3
pip                       20.2.1
plotly                    4.14.3
```

How do I fix the issue? I tried uninstalling and re-installing pandas.

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace?

Comment: @coralvanda here's the full error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Users/ssmm/Desktop/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

Comment: IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "/Users/ssmm/Desktop/pythonProject/venv/bin/python"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.20.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.

Comment: Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' 

Had to chop it off as it's too long. Hope that's readable though

Comment: I think it should work if you delete or rename `test.py`, or upgrade to the latest Dash.

Comment: @coralvanda all good here. I uninstalled and re-installed pandas and numpy and it worked. Thank you!